# How to find specific date occurrences in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am writing a simple MVC 3 application which basically allows the user to enter a range of years(2002-2009), and a specific day and date(Friday, 13th). The result should be a list of MM/DD/YYYY on which that specific day and date occurred.

Input:

Year 1: 2009
Year 2: 2012
Day: Friday
Date(day): 13

Result:

08/13/2010
09/13/2011
...
...
...

Comment: You example doesn't make sense. And what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2001, 01, 01);
        DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2012, 12, 31);

        for (DateTime d11 = d1; d11 < d2; d11 = d11.AddDays(1))
        {
            if (d11.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday && d11.Day == 13)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(d11.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, I believe your answer makes the question more clear

Comment: too much experience with customers am afraid :)